# Date Time and Formula Improvement C#

Tags: c#, date

I got here a scenario where I input an information but the code does does not work. What happen is when I input 12/11/2015, the Address2Panel shows. Which is wrong because there no more date that I can input because Person A is born in 12/11/2015. The logic should Enter addresses for the past 5 years. But it goes wrong if the Birthdate gap is not lesser the 5 years from the current date.

> Person A Birthday = 12/11/2015
>
> Person A StartLiving = 12/11/2015 because its the day he/she was born.
>   Should not display Address2Panel

```
 int CurrentDateInMonths = (((DateTime.Today.Year) * 12) + (DateTime.Today.Month));
    static int AlienMonthsAtCurrentAddress = 0;

        DateTime myDateTime;
        //LivedHere = 12/11/2015
        myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(LivedHere.Text);

        AlienMonthsAtCurrentAddress = (CurrentDateInMonths - (((Convert.ToInt16(myDateTime.Year)) * 12) + Convert.ToInt16(myDateTime.Month)));
        if (AlienMonthsAtCurrentAddress < 60)
        {
            Address2Panel.Visible = true;//shows the Address2Panel
        }
        else
        {
            ClearAddress2Panel();//hides also the Address2Panel
        }
```

Any suggestion how should I improve my formula and date time manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

no need to convert date into months, subtract dates using [DateTime.Subtract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx) method :
*From MSDN, **DateTime.Subtract** Method subtracts the specified date and time from this instance.It returns a **TimeSpan** object which has a property [Days](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx)*

```
static int AlienMonthsAtCurrentAddress = 0;
try
{

    DateTime myDateTime;
    myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(LivedHere.Text);

    // If you don't wish to subtract from today's date use required date in place of DateTime.Now
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract ( myDateTime ); 
    if (span.Days < 60)
    {
        Address2Panel.Visible = true;//shows the Address2Panel
    }
    else
    {
        ClearAddress2Panel();//hides also the Address2Panel
    }

}
catch { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea for DateTime manipulation. But it does not solve my problem. When Person A BirthDate = 12/11/2000, And I put 12/11/2015 as the LivedHere Address. It does not show up the extra field that I need. It should show up because the Idea is to input address for the past 5 years. and 12/11/2015 is not 5 years lesser than the current date which is 8/11/2017

Comment: whatever the dates are , use DateTime.Subtract IMHO offcourse ! i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could check years, months and days with a separately logic, and then get them all together:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015,11,12)
DateTime input = getDate()
int years = input.Year - date.Year - 1
years += If(input.Month > date.Month, 1, 0)
years += If(input.Month = date.Month AndAlso input.Day >= date.Day, 1, 0)
```

This will output the exact number of years between two days (truncating the resulting integer). You'll just have to compare it to 5, in your case